# Assigning address for instruction in object file

Tags: c, linux, process, ld, loader

When we compile any c code with `gcc -c` and do `objdump -d <filename>.o` we see

```
Disassembly of section .text:
0000000000000000 <main>:
 0:   55                      push   %rbp
 1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 4:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
 8:   48 8d 45 fc             lea    -0x4(%rbp),%rax
 c:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
 f:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 . . .
```

But after linking, the offset changes to `gcc -o prog -L/library/path -llibrary *.o`

```
0000000000400644 <main>:
400644:       55                      push   %rbp
400645:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
400648:       48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
40064c:       48 8d 45 fc             lea    -0x4(%rbp),%rax
400650:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
400653:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
```

How the offset is calculated after linking is done?

We basically get 3 set of addresses,
    1. After compiling 
    2. After linking
    3. After Loading

How the above address are related?

Comment: Suppose you have one penny -- it has position 0 in a stack of 1 pennies. Now combine it with 99 other pennies and stick it in a roll -- how is the position of that penny in the roll calculated? That's much like what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc -c` would run the [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) proper (some `cc1`) which produces assembly code, then the [assembler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembler_%28computing%29) (`as`). Check with `gcc -v -c` to understand what exactly is happening.

The compiler (actually `cc1`) is translating your C code into assembly code.

Then the assembler (`as`) is translating that assembly code into an [object file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) (in [Executable & Linkable Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), a.k.a. ELF).

An ELF object file contains segments of bytes (e.g. code or `.text` segment or `.data` segment) with [relocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29) instructions or directives and defines (& uses) symbolic references. Relocation is processor dependent, see e.g. [this list of relocation types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-0690/chapter7-2/index.html) and the [x86-64 ABI spec](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf%E2%80%8E) - for [application binary interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). These relocations are processed by the [linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) (`ld`, started by `gcc`). Read [Levine's *Linkers and loaders* book](http://www.iecc.com/linkers/). So ELF object files contain bytes with relocation instructions and [symbol tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table).

The linker would modify some machine instructions (or other data) according to relocation codes.

Comment: From the book, "To produce an executable program, the linker combines these two object files with a standard startup initialization routine for C programs, and necessary routines from the C library, producing an executable file".                       And we noted that for all the executable we created on the machines had start address `0000000000400644` for `<main>`

Answer (score 2):

You have to remember that the object file contains only *your* code, so it will always be at offset zero.

When you link you add modules from other sources, like the runtime-initialization and library functions. You don't know the size of these objects, or where they will be placed in the resulting executable files, and therefore can't calculate the offset to the different parts of your code yourself. Also, if you have multiple object files, the linker may rearrange them as it sees fit.

What the exact *virtual address* the code will end up in when running, depends partly on the linker, but mostly on the operating system and things like address-space randomization and such.

Answer (score 0):

Each platform/architecture has its specific memory layout that it expects for executables. Its the task of the linker to combine/relocate object files in a way that fits your platform/architecture.

With gcc toolchains, this adaption is done through linker scripts. If you are curious, you can peek into the implementation (default link scripts usually live in a directory called `ldscripts` with `.xbn` file extensions).